# IIS welcome page not working from the local Machine

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

i have an IIS web server installed on windows server 2012 R2, the problem is that when i try to open the `http://localhost` page from the windows server 2012 it fails and displays (explorer cannot display this page), while when i try to access the welcome page from a remote machine it works fine.

Any ideas about the cause for this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the bindings for the website are correct.
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The binding settings are as default for the default web page that comes with IIS, also as i mentioned above the issue is on server side only, from client side i can see the welcome page.

Comment: What happens if you ping localhost on the server?

Comment: It replies with the IPv6, but i also tried to use 127.0.0.1 and the same issue happens.

Comment: Interesting, maybe something in this answer will work? http://serverfault.com/questions/787320/ipv6-website-not-working-in-iis-8

Answer (score 1):

Update,
The problem was fixed, it was an issue with the internet explorer security settings itself, had to remove localhost and 127.0.0.1 from the local intranet zone to the trusted sites zone (Internet Options > security) and the problem was fixed.

Many thanks all for your much appreciated replies.